# Listbox in asp.net not getting selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have multiple dropdown & listbox in my webpage.

I am trying to get a list of `CategoryID` from a `lstCatID` listbox i am able to populate the listbox with category name.

If i remember correctly in first attempt my code worked fine,  after that i made some change then it stated to always get the first item selected x No. of time

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstCatID" runat="server" DataTextField="CategoryName" 
                DataValueField="CategoryID" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="lstListBox">
 </asp:ListBox>



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CatID = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem li in lstCatID.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
           // Response.Write();
            CatID += lstCatID.SelectedItem.Value + ",";
        }
    }
    Response.Write(CatID);
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong i checkd MSDN it show exactly the same way of doing it.

May be i am doing something wrong.

Just to add using firefox i am able to see multiple selected value have selected property.

```
<option value="3" selected="selected">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="29" selected="selected">Three</option>
<option value="25" selected="selected">Four</option>
<option value="22" >Five</option>
```

My output in this case will be `3,3,3`

I would appreciate help in this regard

Comment: Do you need to enable the view state?

Comment: @DaiBok, Yes i need to as i have several controls on the page..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting it to the same value every time:

```
foreach (ListItem li in lstCatID.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
       // you are always using lstCatID.SelectedItem.Value.
        CatID += lstCatID.SelectedItem.Value + ",";
    }
}
```

When you actually want the value of the item in your loop that is selected:

```
foreach (ListItem li in lstCatID.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected == true)
    {
        // get the value of the item in your loop
        CatID += li.Value + ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: I new something was wrong with my logic.. You are right. But i will prefer to use the solution using LINQ which i clean

Comment: Yes I like the LINQ answer too... just wanted you to see issue tho :)

Comment: I will mark you answer since it addressed the actual issue which was logic related. Some time small mistake are unnoticed.. Thanks..

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure what is wrong with the logic i am using.

I came across a nice solution using LINQ.

This single statement works great & gets me the desired results.

```
string values = String.Join(", ", lstCatID.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value).ToArray());
```

RESULT: 3,29,25

Answer (score 4):

Try to add **Page.IsPostback** on your Page_Load like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do your API code here unless you want it to occur only the first
    // time the page loads, in which case put it in the IF statement below.
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CatID = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem li in lstCatID.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected )
        {
           // TODO: Whatever you are doing with a selected item.
        }
    }
    Response.Write(CatID);
}
```

Once i was facing the same problem and i made Postback mistake.

Hope it works.

Comment: I use it on all the page `Page.IsPostback` but how will make different to this as i have my code on button event

Comment: I also tried before `if (li.selected)` this didn't made any different.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: If you databind a webcontrol no events are triggered and all changes are lost.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Good to see you, then how i can solve this issue. I multiple ListBox on my web page.

Comment: (li.Selected) doesn't make many difference but Page.IsPostBack will make a difference...you are using (li.selected) if it's selected then it will always return True, that's why i remove that true from your code..

Comment: @Rahul, i am using code in the same manner you have shown but i a still getting this problem. I am not sure is it the logic of problem metioned by `TimSchmelter`

Comment: Your code looks fine according to me but many times only `PostBack` is the reason of the error in such kind of cases.

Comment: Look at the solution i have posted, I am still puzzled what this is happening. One can find similar examples on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5kfekd2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Get the selected  items using linq

```
var selected = lstCatID.Items.Where(i => i.Selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Minutes later I found a solution:

```
If lstLocations.Items.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To lstLocations.Items.Count - 1
                If lstLocations.Items(i).Selected Then
                    'insert command
                    Dim selectedItem As String = lstLocations.Items(i).Text
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

This worked fine in my scenario