# LINQ - SELECT NEW - Include ListBox Selected Items

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

Using ASP.NET 4.0

I am having trouble on the LINQ to get the .srvc_id to be the checked values and my query below is only populating the first check box for my object.

Code

```
If Not IsNothing(lbServices.SelectedItem) Then
            'NEW record INSERT values from list box to table.
            myServices = (From item In lbServices.Items
                                    Where item.Selected
                                    Select New tbl_parent_to_child With
                                            {
                                                    .id = myServices.child_id,

                                                    ----- .srvc_id is where I am stuck any help would be great.  It is repeating the first selected check box.

                                                    .srvc_id = lbServices.SelectedValue,
                                                    .Active = True,
                                                    .CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                                                    .CreateByID = SecurityMethods.GetLoginUserId(Session("AuthUser")),
                                                    .UpdateDate = DateTime.Now,
                                                    .UpdateByID = SecurityMethods.GetLoginUserId(Session("AuthUser"))
                                            }).ToList()
            For Each item In myServices 
                ctx.tbl_parent_to_child .Add(item)
            Next
        End If

Try
            ctx.SaveChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Master.HandleStatusMessageEvent((New StatusMessageEventArgs("Email a screen shot of this error to the Help Desk", StatusMessageType.ErrorMsg)))
        End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use the item variable, `.srvc_id = CInt(item.Value)`

This is similar to [Listbox in asp.net not getting selected items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338246/listbox-in-asp-net-not-getting-selected-items)